# SSL timeout when calling an URL via Python and requests

Tags: python, ssl, https, openssl, python-requests

I'm stuck with the following case: when calling an HTTPS link from Python and `requests`, I'm getting a timeout on my Ubuntu laptop, as well as on Linuxes I've tried in VirtualBox and another laptop. However, the same Python code returns valid response on Windows 7, Mac OS X and latest FreeBSD. The problem appeared around two weeks ago, and I suspect it's probably because of something was changed on the server, which affected only Linux network stack. Any ideas why actually it may happen and how to fix it are welcome.

Below are the details.

- Python version I've used: latest, 2.7.11
- `requests` version: 2.10
- Operating systems I've tried: Ubuntu 16.04, Ubuntu 15.10, Fedora 23, CentOS 6, Windows 7, FreeBSD, Mac OS X.

**Note:** all significant data below was skipped due to NDA.

The actual Python code which fails:

```
import requests
import logging
import httplib as http_client
import ssl


http_client.HTTPConnection.debuglevel = 1

logging.basicConfig()
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
requests_log = logging.getLogger("requests.packages.urllib3")
requests_log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
requests_log.propagate = True

url = 'https://subdomain.example1.com/products/12345'
cert = ('example.pem', 'example.key')
response = requests.get(url=url,
                        params={'locale': 'en_US'},
                        headers={'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Accept': 'application/json'},
                        timeout=10.0,
                        cert=cert,
                        verify=False,
                        cookies=None)
print response
```

Result of running the code above on Linuxes:

```
$ python req.py 
INFO:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): subdomain.example1.com
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "req.py", line 23, in <module>
    cookies=None)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 67, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 53, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 468, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 576, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 449, in send
    raise ReadTimeout(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='subdomain.example1.com', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=10.0)
```

Result of the same code on Linux with timeout set to 300.0:

```
$ python req.py 
INFO:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): subdomain.example1.com
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "req.py", line 23, in <module>
    cookies=None)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 67, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 53, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 468, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 576, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 447, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: ("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'ssl3_read_bytes', 'sslv3 alert unexpected message')],)",)
```

A correct Python code run result taken from FreeBSD:

```
$ python req.py  
INFO:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): subdomain.example1.com
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:821: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html
  InsecureRequestWarning)
send: 'GET /products/12345?locale=en_US HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: subdomain.example1.com\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\nAccept: application/json\r\nUser-Agent: python-requests/2.10.0\r\nContent-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n\r\n'
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n'
header: Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
header: Cache-Control: private
header: Expires: Wed, 31 Dec 1969 17:00:00 MST
header: Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
header: Transfer-Encoding: chunked
header: Date: Thu, 09 Jun 2016 16:13:37 GMT
DEBUG:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:"GET /products/12345?locale=en_US HTTP/1.1" 200 None
<Response [200]>
```

A try from `openssl`:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect subdomain.example1.com:443 -cert example.pem -key example.key
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 CN = Root.Example2.com
verify return:1
depth=1 DC = com, DC = example3, CN = ca-example3
verify return:1
depth=0 ST = Colorado, L = Boulder, O = Example4.com, OU = WebOps, CN = *.example1.com
verify return:1
139622025893528:error:140943F2:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert unexpected message:s3_pkt.c:1472:SSL alert number 10
139622025893528:error:140790E5:SSL routines:ssl23_write:ssl handshake failure:s23_lib.c:177:
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/ST=Colorado/L=Boulder/O=Example4.com/OU=WebOps/CN=*.example1.com
   i:/DC=com/DC=example3/CN=ca-example3
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
........ SKIPPED .........                                                                                                                                                                                                              
-----END CERTIFICATE-----                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
subject=/ST=Colorado/L=Boulder/O=Example4.com/OU=WebOps/CN=*.example1.com                                                                                                                                                                                                          
issuer=/DC=com/DC=example3/CN=ca-example3                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
---                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
Acceptable client certificate CA names                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
/O=Example4.com/OU=WebOps/CN=cl_ABCDEFGHI                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
/O=Example4.com/OU=WebOps/CN=cl_QWERTYUIO                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
/CN=Root.Example2.com
/DC=com/DC=example3/CN=ca-example3
/O=Example4.com/OU=WebOps/CN=cl_ASDFGHJKL
/O=Example4.com/OU=WebOps/CN=cl_ZXCVBNabc
/O=Example4.com/OU=WebOps/CN=cl_poiuytrew
Client Certificate Types: RSA sign, DSA sign, ECDSA sign
Requested Signature Algorithms: ECDSA+SHA512:RSA+SHA512:ECDSA+SHA384:RSA+SHA384:ECDSA+SHA256:RSA+SHA256:ECDSA+SHA224:RSA+SHA224:ECDSA+SHA1:RSA+SHA1:DSA+SHA1:RSA+MD5
Shared Requested Signature Algorithms: ECDSA+SHA512:RSA+SHA512:ECDSA+SHA384:RSA+SHA384:ECDSA+SHA256:RSA+SHA256:ECDSA+SHA224:RSA+SHA224:ECDSA+SHA1:RSA+SHA1:DSA+SHA1
Peer signing digest: SHA512
Server Temp Key: ECDH, P-256, 256 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 2573 bytes and written 4570 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
    Session-ID: 57591435C56B9FDFXXXBB896F8140E7B72EE07A2ACDB0446F0AB04C5D2928FD1
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: F830C1F0330391B5XXX3E58F07C23D7A8C2020F824C0C4389D798CCA16A6AD5D556881671001A7DD6641AC4739BE2E28
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1465455669
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

The host seems valid, I'm able to ping it, `openssl` call from any OS, including Linux boxes shows it's alive and responds to requests.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I understand you correctly openssl s_client works from all machines but python/ssl does not? Are you sure that you are using Python 2.7.11  on FreeBSD too because the warning about InsecureRequest... suggests a difference to the version running on Linux. Does s_client still work if you use SNI with  the `-servername` parameter?

Comment: openssl s_client works correctly on all machines, yes. And Python/requests works only on non-Linuxes.

Comment: Yes, it's Python 2.7.11 on FreeBSD, just checked.

Comment: Tried `-servername`, it looks like it doesn't change anything. The output of `openssl` is just the same as before.

Comment: Very strange. Then I would suggest to look at the network layer (i.e. packet capture) to see where it hangs. Ideally captures will be done both at the client and the server side in case some network equipment causes the problems. One could also try to decrease MTU, switch off ECN or similar. See also https://squidproxy.wordpress.com/2007/06/05/thinsg-to-look-at-if-websites-are-hanging/

Comment: Hmm I have to say that the problem has disappeared magically by probably changing some of the settings on the client's server. I neither cannot reproduce it nor get a reasonable info what actually happened. Looks like the question should be closed then.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem were caused by bugs in virtualbox when using nat network across several versions. According to [this issue](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/16084), the bug was fixed in release 5.1.10. But I got the same problem in Virtual Box 5.1.12 on a Windows Host.

Comment: Great to hear they've fixed it. And we've meanwhile switched to Docker, so one more problem is gone. Thanks for mentioning!